# Is it possible to have a transparent video playing in QT application

Tags: qt, video, qml

Some codecs alow alpha transparency, like flv, Mov and Webm. I am about to build a QT app and i want to know if it will be possible to make a video player using QML which will support transparency and i will be able to see the background of my app even when the video is playing.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a widget to have a level of transparency, so if the video stream is also transparent it should show transparent to the widget and then if the widget is also transparent then through that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you already looked at the QML Video example which ships with the current QTCreator / QT 5.1.1 SDK package?. If you wish to draw a transparent/translucent video window, you can modify the 'opacity' property of a QML VideoOutput element to have translucent Video overlay.
You can build the example if you download and install the SDK.

Here's is the online link to the example:
[QML Video Example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtmultimedia/multimedia-video-qmlvideo.html)

Take a close look at this file:
[VideoItem.qml](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtmultimedia/multimedia-video-qmlvideo-qml-qmlvideo-videoitem-qml.html)

You can modify the opacity as shown below:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtMultimedia 5.0

VideoOutput {
    id: root
    height: width
    source: mediaPlayer
    opacity: 0.7 // Set the opacity as you wish
...
```

You can play around with the example by importing any type of video files you wish.